# How does lappend on $varName work?

Tags: tcl

I made a stupid mistake and gave `lappend` a `$` prefixed variable name. So the following:

```
> set l [list e1 e2 e3]
e1 e2 e3
> puts $l
e1 e2 e3
> lappend $l e4
e4
```

I know this is wrong usage, and it doesn't work as I expected... but to my surprise it works somehow. I.e the interpreter doesn't bail on it. It seems like valid TCL, but I cannot figure out what does it do exactly.

I thought it might expand  `$l` and execute `lappend e1 e2 e3 e4` but there is no `e1` variable.

Where does `e4` gets appended to? A variable named `$l` (is it possible to have such a variable name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets appended to a variable named `e1 e2 e3`, i.e. the blanks are part of the name. The number of arguments in the command invocation is preserved during variable substitution, so if `$l` is a single argument, the value that it expands to remains a single argument, just as if you had written `{e1 e2 e3}`. If you instead had written `lappend {*}$l e4` the invocation would have been `lappend e1 e2 e3 e4` (command name and four arguments, appending the values `e2`, `e3`, and `e4` to the variable named `e1`), assuming Tcl 8.5 or later.

Documentation: [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm)

Comment: Oh, so `puts ${e1 e2 e3}` was what I was missing, to retrieve the result of the command. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

% set l [list e1 e2 e3]

e1 e2 e3

% lappend $l e4  <<<<< This means, we are creating a new variable "$l" and appending in to it. - Here is where we need to make a change.

e4

% lappend l e4 <<<< This is what we want ---> here we are appending in to our variable "l"

e1 e2 e3 e4

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. We are not creating a variable `$l`we are creating a variable named `e1 e2 e3`. My guess was that it had been `$l` but I was wrong.